# A Number theoretic inequality including floor functions.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, induction, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Prove that [x] + $\frac{[2x]}{2} + ..... \frac{[nx]}{n}$ $ \le $ $[nx]$ $x \in R^+$

Where [.] is the greatest integer function. - USAMO 1981.

Usually, we can find the solutions of USAMO problems pretty easily but all solutions of this i found were wrong.

My attempt: I went on with induction and reached [kx +k] $\ge$ [kx] + $\frac{[kx+x]}{k+1} $ but turns out this wasn't true. So inequality must be very weak.

I am absolutely baffled by this problem, any solution would be really appreciated. Thanks!

I AM LOOKING FOR A NON CALCULUS solution

Comment: Index should be $k$ instead of $n$ in the $\sum$ I imagine?

Comment: @MartinR i am looking for a non calculus solution

Comment: As written the left-hand side of the inequality is exactly equal to the right-hand side. I suspect the other commenters are correct.

Comment: i am sorry for the mistakes, i don't know how to write sigma. i RECKON it'll be more understandable now @GregMartin

Comment: what about [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1302311p6989779:)?